# Find closest location between user's coordinates and coordinates array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, geolocation, comparison

I want to create a function that takes as parameters:

1. An array filled of coordinates
2. The current user location

And return the closest location between the user's location and the array locations.

**Here are my locations:**

```
let coord1 = CLLocation(latitude: 52.45678, longitude: 13.98765)
let coord2 = CLLocation(latitude: 52.12345, longitude: 13.54321)
let coord3 = CLLocation(latitude: 48.771896, longitude: 2.270748000000026)
```

**User location function:**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
    let long = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    let lat = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    let coordinates = [ coord1, coord2, coord3]

    userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

    print("my location: \(userLocation)")
    closestLocation(locations: coordinates, closestToLocation: userLocation)
}
```

**Coordinates comparison function**

```
    func closestLocation(locations: [CLLocation], closestToLocation location: CLLocation) -> CLLocation? {

    if let closestLocation: CLLocation = locations.min(by: { userLocation.distance(from: $0) < userLocation.distance(from: $1) }) {

        let distanceMeters = userLocation.distance(from: closestLocation)
        let distanceKM = distanceMeters / 1000

        print("closest location: \(closestLocation), distance: \(distanceKM)")
        return closestLocation
    } else {
        print("coordinates is empty")
        return nil
    }

}
```

It actually doesn't working and my `closestLocation` function is always returning a huge distance between the two "closest locations".

**Input parameters**

```
closestLocation(locations: coordinates, closestToLocation: userLocation)
```

**Edit**

Result when I print `closestLocation` and `distanceKM`:

```
closest location: <+48.77189600,+2.27074800> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 14/01/2017 00:16:04 heure normale d’Europe centrale, distance: 5409.0
```

As you can see, the distance (in km) is very huge while these locations are the same city.

Comment: What do you get when you print `location`? Also try print out `distance` in each iteration to see what values they are.

Comment: Edited the question with all you need!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Array.min(by: )` to find the minimum element according to a sorting criteria (distance in your case):

```
func closestLocation(locations: [CLLocation], closestToLocation location: CLLocation) -> CLLocation? {
    if let closestLocation = locations.min(by: { location.distance(from: $0) < location.distance(from: $1) }) {
        print("closest location: \(closestLocation), distance: \(location.distance(from: closestLocation))")
        return closestLocation
    } else {
        print("coordinates is empty")
        return nil
    }
}

// We know the answer is coord3 and the distance is 0    
closestLocation(locations: [coord1, coord2, coord3], closestToLocation: coord3)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But why the function is returning a distance of 8968450 meters?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Can you give the input paramaters passed into the `closestLocation` function?

Comment: Edited the question with all you need!

Comment: Have you checked what your `userLocation` was [on a map](http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html)? That looks like the distance from Apple's HQ to Germany

Comment: Don't assume, verify it

Comment: `locationManager(_, didUpdateLocations: )` only gives you your real location if you are testing on a real device. If you doing this in the Simulator, set a custom location in `Debug > Location > Custom Location...`

Comment: Resolved: I used to run my app on emulator. Now I'm running it with my device and this is working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: oh ok, you answered at the same time! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133122/discussion-between-greenpoison-onetv-and-code-different).